# Converting from div to table or parsing PDF in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I'm developing a WebApp in which I take an invoice converted from PDF to HTML, then parse the invoice lines.

I have a `div` in my main window which displays the contents.

But when I display the contents from the invoice in that `div`, all the contents appear overlapped.

In the converted invoice there is no table, only `divs` with absolute positioning. I can't make it any other way at least with this aproach, because that's the way the converter works.

So, as a solution I'm converting from "div to table", trying to decide when there is a change of row or not, based on the top parameter from the corresponding div.

However besides the invoice data, I also have the invoice header. I'm having difficulties to decide if the table is the same or not.

But so far, I think the solution passes through making 3 tables, one for the company logo, one for the header, and one for the data.

But I need all these tables to appear in the correct positions and with the correct sizes.

At the moment, I'm not allowed to paste invoice examples, and as I'm stuck in an early stage (close to the algorithm stage). I don't think any examples of my code and of the invoices could help anyone to understand the situation better.

But I promise to update this with examples soon.

As an alternative solution I could parse the PDF myself, but I haven't found a way to do it so far.

I'm using PHP to make the WebApp and verypdf pdf2html to make the conversion.

I know with that little information, is hard to get help.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I've just got an idea, but I think it won't work between de logo and the header. When I'm making the decision if the row changed or not I could use a counter and a buffer instead of changing the inputed html directly, then if the number of <td></td>s changed I would surround it with <table> and </table> thou making the separation between tables. Although, both the logo table and the header table have only one column and there is situations in which they are alined, and situations in which they are not. To check this I could use the left parameter of the div. But I'm not sure of this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying to cure the overlapping itself. For example you could strip all the styling information from the DIVs after the PDF is parsed into DIVs. Then you can apply your own styles.
It might be useful to know if all the invoices are in the same format/arrangement, or not.

Comment: I suppose the invoices are in the same format/arrangement once the converter is always the same. But yes, this really could be a great sollution. It would allow me to make a standardization in a 'my system' level despite the original/PDF format. Although I got a workaround which I'm using right now! The only reason I still not update this post is because I whish to understand this kind of situation better.

Comment: After all the problem in the visualization of the invoices was not related to the divs but to some wrong extra parameters in the HTML tag. That is the work around I'm using! Despite that, I still need the conversion on the parse time. thanks for all the help.